# How to find all cities or zip codes(location details) from google map with in one mile radius from marker?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, google-maps-markers

I need to find all cities or zip codes inside a radius (ex: 1 mile) from google map where i have marker on some location (ex: california) using javascript in web application. All the cities or zip codes(or lat and lng) inside one mile radius of california needed to be fetched. No databases. Is there any google map api for it ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Looking for some google api functions in their documentations

Comment: checout geocoding API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1

Comment: Thank you jaydeep, i found a solution from the link provided above(using nearbysearch func. of google map)